# How to know a QGraphicsItem is moving

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have a child class of QGraphicsItem with Selectable, Movable and SendsScenePositionChanges flags. When I select many items and moving them, all recieves itemChange event. Is there any way to detect in *itemChanged* if the item is moving? (or other way but in item level not scene level)

I tried to check if the left button was held down, but this way seems not working.

```
QVariant BaseItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    if (change == ItemScenePositionHasChanged)
    {
        Qt::MouseButtons btns = QApplication::mouseButtons();
        if (btns & Qt::LeftButton) {
            // The left button is pressed.
            mIsMoving = true;
        }
        else
        {
            mIsMoving = false; // this line is never triggered
        }
    }

    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

Edit:

Let me describe my original needs, there are `item1` and `item2`, an arrow connect between them, let's call it `arrowItem`, if I move `item1`, the arrow also needs to automatically adjust the shape to apply the new position, let's call this shape `autoShape`. User can also adjust the shape of the arrow, let's call it `customShape`.

Now, If `item1` and `item2` are selected at the same time and moved together, the arrow (has `customShape`) just need to move with them, no need to adjust the shape automatically . My current code flow is as follows: the movement of `item1` triggers the update of the arrow, then the arrow needs to check whether `item2` is also moving. If `item2` is not moving, then automatically adjust the shape of the arrow. If `item2` is also moving and the movement is same as `item1`, then Just move the `arrowItem` directly, no need to adjust the shape. Both `item1` and `item2` may be children of some other items.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to enable `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag to receive this event. Also, there are two similar but different events: `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange` and `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged`. The first one is triggered when the item is moving, and the second one is after it finishes moving. The difference is that `.pos()` returns different values if called in the event callback. For the first event, it returns the original item position, and in the case of the second event, it returns a new position. Both events have new positions in their argument.

More about those events: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemChange-enum

EDIT:

Based on the comments from the author of the question. After testing, it seems that `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged` and `QGraphicsItem::ItemScenePositionHasChanged` (which is useful to the author) are regularly and very often emitted after `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange`.

In my case, when grabbing the item and shaking the mouse, the `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange` was emitted exactly 2 times between each `QGraphicsItem::ItemScenePositionHasChanged`.

The only experimental difference I see between them is that in `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange` callback, by calling `.pos()`, you can still access old item position, while in `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged` and `QGraphicsItem::ItemScenePositionHasChanged` calling `.pos()` results in a new item position.

So if for some reason the old item position is needed, then it is sufficient to additionally store it as a member of the derived class and update it in the `QGraphicsItem::ItemScenePositionHasChanged` callback when you're done.

EDIT 2:

With more information on the problem from the author. My approach would be to implement a "movement check" in the following way. If all of the selected items move together, then when `item1` moves, it checks whether `item2` is also currently selected (thereby, it also moves) with `item1->scene()->selectedItems()->indexOf(item2)`.

If the result is `-1`, it means that `item2` is not selected, hence, it is not moving and the arrow shape needs to be updated; otherwise, move the arrow along with both items.

Comment: I need a scene position change, but `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange` seems only happens when local position changes (not tested) , which means if the parent is moving, there is NO notification. it's wierd there is `QGraphicsItem::ItemScenePositionHasChanged` but NO `QGraphicsItem::ItemScenePositionChange` exist

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I would look into mouse events for the graphics item. Similar to what you tried in your question, but instead of `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()`, have a look at `QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent()`, `QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent()`, `QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent()`

Especially for `QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent()`: "If you do receive this event, you can be certain that this item also received a mouse press event, and that this item is the current mouse grabber."

Comment: Consider this scenario, if I have item1, item2, select two items, hold down left button on item1 to drag, at this time item2 is also moving, but will not receive mouse event.

Comment: I think you've hit the limitation of the current `QGraphicsItem`. In our project, we have a similar need, but our graphics items in question are direct children of the scene so we can capture it with `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange` signal

Comment: I did some testing and updated the answer accordingly

Comment: please check my edit